# Как перехватить (получить) вывод "eval(command)" в переменную?

Tags: python, консоль, вывод

Нужно выполнить `eval(code)`. Допустим, `code` = `'print('hw')'`. Результат сохранить в строку. Имею в виду то, что code вводится пользователем. Нужно получить "hw".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для перехвата вывода можно использовать [contextlib.redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout), а для сохранения перехваченного [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO).

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/contextlib__redirect__stdout_stderr/redirect__to_file_like_object.py#L11)

```
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with StringIO() as f, redirect_stdout(f):
    code = "print('hw')"
    eval(code)

    # Read from IO
    result = f.getvalue()

print(repr(result))  # 'hw\n'
```

---

**PS.**

Есть два потока вывода `stdout` и `stderr` (в консоли этот вывод, как правило, закрашен красным цветом).

В первый по умолчанию пишет `print`, а вот всякие исключения могут быть выведены в `stderr` и [для перехвата их](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a6e817609d78bcd632c8b01fe353b0dd87e68c93/contextlib__redirect__stdout_stderr/catch_stdout_and_stderr__Exception.py#L15) нужно использовать [contextlib.redirect_stderr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr):

```
with StringIO() as f, redirect_stdout(f), redirect_stderr(f):
    ...
```